# Enumerate mysql table and encrypt fields

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encryption, encode

I am working on a CI 1.2 to CI 3.x upgrade.  I have 3 tables with 11 fields that were encoded with SHA1 in CI 1.x.  CI 3 uses AES-256.  In effect I need to execute an UPDATE tablex set (fielda = $this->encrypt->encode_from_legacy(fielda)) which isn't valid SQL.

How can I enumerate each row of the target table and update the row with the result of the encoding function?

I can't think of a way to decode and encode in native SQL statements using different ciphers and modes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: SHA1 is a one-way hash function, the original input **can not** be recovered. AES-256 is recoverable encryption where the original input **can** be recovered.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as **`password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. With PHP `password_hash` and `password_verify` are arguably the best solution.

Comment: you would most likely have to `SELECT` the records you what to convert.  use PHP decode and then re-encode.  Then `INSERT` the newly encoded data into your new table.  If I understand your question.  Like everyone else said dont try on your own to store passwords you care about

Comment: @Austin it is not possible to recover the opriginal passwords from a SHA1 hash.

Comment: My mistake.  The Passwords are SHA1 in CI v1.x but not the subject of this post.  

Perhaps I need to be more specific. My question is related to encoded data. This is encoded patient hippa data.  I have the keys and I can decode and encode the data but I need to update en masse and my available decode/encode function has to be executed for every row of each table for multiple fields in each table.

Comment: maybe go with 2 steps - first decode and store in old system; next encode with encryption class in new CI

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with to re-encrypt old MD5 hashed data to AES-256 data.  (NOT PASSWORD data).

```
function doUpdates ($query = null) {
    $this->load->library('encrypt');        //obsolete MD5 (PHP 7.x not supported)
    $this->load->library('encryption');     // CIv3 AES-256
    $dbobject=array(
    'appointments'    => array('completion_notes'),
    'health_profiles' => array('allergies', 
                               'pregnancy_history', 
                               'medications', 
                               'hospitalizations',
                               'social_history',
                               'personal_illness',
                               'family_illness',
                               'height',
                               'weight')
    );

    foreach($dbobject as $table=>$fields) {
        echo "Fix table: ".$table."<br/>";
        $query = $this->db->get($table)->result_array();
        foreach ($query as $row) {
            foreach($fields as $field){
               //decrypt from legacy MD5 to AES-256
               $after = $this->encryption->encrypt(
                        $this->encrypt->decode(
                            $this->encrypt->encode_from_legacy($row[$field])));
                $sql_set = $field."= '".$after."',";
            } //end foreach field

            //remove last comma
            $sql_set = substr_replace($sql_set, "", -1);

            switch ($table) {
                case "appointments":
                    $primarykey = "appointment_id";
                    break;
                case "health_profiles":
                    $primarykey = "health_profile_id";
                    break;
            } //end switch
            echo "Encrypting data for primary key: ".$row[$primarykey]."<br/>";
            $this->db->simple_query('update '.$table. " set ". $sql_set." where ".$primarykey." = '".$row[$primarykey]."'");
        }  // end for each row  
    } //end foreach table
} // end createUpdates
```

} // end recrypt controller